# Clear multiple selects with the same ID

Tags: javascript, html

I have some select fields but all of them are with the same ID.

```
<select id="works" name="works[]">
    <option selected="" value="">-select-</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select id="works" name="works[]">
    <option selected="" value="">-select-</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
    <option value="F">F</option>
</select>
```

How should I add the button which would set all selects with the same id/name to their first option (-select-)?

Comment: IDs should be unique.

Comment: Use `class="works"` instead and use `document.getElementsByClassName('works')` to find the elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs of the elements in an HTML page should be unique to avoid any unwanted bugs.

To solve your problem, you can select the dropdowns by the name and then set the value to `''` (the `value` of the first `option` tag).

```js
document.querySelector('#reset')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('select[name="works[]"]')
      .forEach(item => {
        item.value = '';
      });
  });
```

```html
<select id="works" name="works[]">
  <option selected="" value="">-select-</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select id="works" name="works[]">
  <option selected="" value="">-select-</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
  <option value="F">F</option>
</select>

<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will solve your problem. This solution is based on Javascript.

**Happy Coding**

```js
function selectOne(){
  var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
  for(var i = 0;i<select.length;i++)
    {
      if(select[i].name == "works[]"){
        select[i].selectedIndex= "0";
      }
    }

}
```

```html
<select id="works" name="works[]">
    <option selected="" value="">-select-</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select id="works" name="works[]">
    <option selected="" value="">-select-</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
    <option value="F">F</option>
</select>
<button onclick="selectOne()">Select First</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

`$('#works')` will only return first element in dom with this id.

You can use name to set all fields:

```
$('name=works[]').val('')
```

This is jquery solution

Comment: This question isn't tagged with [jquery].

Comment: id must be unique. jQuery doesn't behave properly with not unique id

Comment: will not behave properly means what? @LelioFaieta

Comment: @31piy as you probably know jquery will stop to the first occurrence of the id

Comment: this is what i said @LelioFaieta

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli -- your answer is still incorrect, even if jQuery is used. Try to run it.

Comment: @31piy i read the question. The point is that if op has an invalid markup he shouldn't just receive a "workaround" answer